# Dalekjs ERROR: dalek-browser-phantomjs: Could not start Ghost Driver

Tags: gruntjs, dalekjs

just found Dalekjs and tried out their "Getting Started".

I use it together with grunt but I get this message after "grunt dalek":
Running "dalek:dist" (dalek) task
Fatal error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I have this here included in my Gruntfile.js

```
  dalek: {
      options: {
          browser: ['phantomjs']
      },
      dist: {
          src: ['tests/test.js']
      }
  }
```

And my tests/test.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    'Page title is correct': function (test) {
            test
                .open('http://google.com')
                .assert.title().is('Google', 'It has title')
                .done();
        }
    };
```

If I try this "dalek tests/test.js" i get this message:

> > ERROR: dalek-browser-phantomjs: Could not start Ghost Driver

Any ideas? already tried to remove dalek and phantomjs and install it again

Comment: Interesting issue.
The error comes straight from PhantomJS. Could you please tell me a bit more about your setup? Which operating system do you use, which node version, etc.

Also, could you please post the contents of your package.json, I would like to know, which version from dalek is pulled down from npm.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure. Node version: v0.10.18. And this is in my package.json:         "grunt-dalek": "~0.2.0",
"dalekjs": "0.0.8",
"dalek-browser-chrome": "0.0.8". I use a mac running mountain lion, my phantomjs version is 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

you have an old process running, find it and kill it

```
$ ps -lA | grep dalek
  501 65879   225     4006   0  31  0  3053832  44328 -      T                   0 ttys002    0:00.46 node /usr/local/bin/dalek test.js
  501 65881 65879     400a   0  33  0   777876  50968 -      T                   0 ttys002    0:00.75 .../node_modules/dalekjs/node_modules/dalek-browser-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --webdriver 9001 --ignore-ssl-errors=true
  501 66135   225     4006   0  31  0  2432784    496 -      R+                  0 ttys002    0:00.00 grep dalek

$ kill -9 65881
$ kill -9 65879
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sadly... that was not the solution :( still same error.. i double checked that process was really killed and it still didnt work

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and good luck to find your solution